# concatenate inside indirect excel formula

Tags: concatenation, excel-indirect

I've been looking for some way to dynamically reference another workbook of excel using concatenate and indirect. And just get more and more frustrated.

This is how my problem looks like.
[Concatenate inside Indirect formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C3As.jpg)
How do I make my formula in cell 'B3' work?

Answer (score 0):

From the picture it appears that you are missing an apostrophe at the beginning of your reference. It should look like this:

```
'D:\path\[Filename.xlsx]sheet 1'!$D$6
```

`#REF!` might as well be caused by just wrong filename. Please check it.

And finally: the referenced file must be open for this formula to work. Do not use `INDIRECT()` to extract data from other files stored somewhere in system - this is not possible and should be avoided because file references generated from text strings cannot be tracked from Data / Edit Links menu. You should consider using regular formula links to other files instead - you can easily refresh your references from said menu.

Comment: thank you for your answer taosique, 

on next row of my image there is result from paste value and giving "=" so i don't think i the #ref is caused by wrong filename. I don't open the source workbook and the formula is working just fine.

Comment: Do you have apostrophe in the beginning in `B1`?

Comment: Because it does not look so. If it was generated by concatenate, it should appear in cell. If you typed it, apostrophe is not visible because it is used as text qualifier and this value will not contain initial apostrophe if passed to formula.